# Formatting Cells on Gridview from SQL Data Reader

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, sqldatareader, itemdatabound

I have a Grid view which populates through my SQL data reader

Grid View:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridviewALL" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Search_ItemDataBound">
</asp:GridView>
```

SQL Data Reader:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT en.dpCreatedDT AS 'Time Received', en.enStatusCH AS 'Status', en.enNotificationNoNI AS 'LSBUD Ref', cm.cmpersonfirstch AS 'First Name', cm.cmPersonLastCH AS 'Last Name', cm.cmcompanynamech AS 'Company' FROM dp_enquiry en JOIN dp_caller_master cm ON (en.encmcallerkeyfk = cm.cmCallerKeyNI) WHERE en.ennotificationnoni = @JobnoALL", conn);
        try
        {
            SqlParameter search = new SqlParameter();
            search.ParameterName = "@JobnoALL";
            search.Value = JobnoALL.Text.Trim();
            cmd.Parameters.Add(search);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(dr);
            gridviewALL.DataSource = dt;
            gridviewALL.DataBind();
        }
```

I'm trying to change the format of a cell in the grid view when the text equals a value, I've done this using a listview before but the Gridview steps seems different. I have the following which doesn't seem to be working any suggestions?

```
private void Search_ItemDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridItemEventArgs e)
{
    string CurrentColumn = e.Item.Cells[1].Text;
    if (CurrentColumn == "PROC")
    {
        e.Item.Cells[1].Text = "Creating PDF";
    }
    else if (CurrentColumn == "CLOS")
    {
        e.Item.Cells[1].Text = "Complete";
        e.Item.Cells[1].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
    }
}
```

Comment: try and add an attribute to the cell like `e.Item.Cells[1].Attributes.Add("class", "then your style")` and then have a css Background-Color applied to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It must be reading the header, you need to check if its a `DataRow`:-

```
 if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
 {
    string CurrentColumn = e.Item.Cells[1].Text;
    //your code goes here..
 }
```

Also, I would suggest you to use [DataBinder.Eval](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4hx47hfe(v=vs.110).aspx) method instead to avoid hard-coding of cell index as it may result in error if order of columns change.

```
string CurrentColumn = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "yourColumnName").ToString();
```

**Update:**

Just noticied you are using `ItemDataBound` which is an event for `DataGrid` and not `Gridview`. Use `RowDataBound` event instead:-

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridviewALL" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="gridviewALL_RowDataBound">
</asp:GridView>
```

Your rowDataBound event should look like this:-

```
protected void gridviewALL_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //your code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul, the `DataGridItemEvent` doesn't seem to like the `Row.RowType` do I need to change something else?

Comment: @Cory - Hey ya it should be `OnRowDataBound` not `OnItemDataBound` since you are using Gridview not DataGrid. Will update the answer.

Comment: Oh I see, I've changed the `OnItemDataBound` to `OnRowDataBound`. The error I'm getting is `DataGridItemEventArgs Does Not Contain A Definition for Row`

Comment: @Cory - You need to change the definition as well. I have posted that too.

Comment: Thank you this is what I was looking for! I was getting confused as I've only ever used this method with Listviews.